# WP admin page gives 404

Tags: wp-admin, 404-error

I have a problem with my admin page of the site http://www.fotoexpo202.nl . I can not reach the inlog anymore of this page: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This is what happened: I tried to remove, in the WP adminpage, a part of site URL. This must be: http://www.fotoexpo.nl/show and I tried to remove show. Unfortunately after saving, it went down. I also tried to contact my provider but they will not help me. My provider is Budget Webhosting in Holland. So, now, I can not anymore reach my site by WP-Admin and also the site is totally broken. What can I do to get it back? Thanks so much for helping! Regards Peter

Comment: When you say you tried to remove `/show`, what is `/show` and how did you remove it?

Comment: @ktscript comments are for asking clarifying questions, you shouldn't be moving users offsite or soliciting work, your account could be disabled

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `siteurl` or `home` value got modified when you tried to modify the site URL in WP admin? If so, it might make the front-end and the WP admin inaccessible because it is looking for WordPress in a directory in which it doesn't exist.

### Fixing it in the database

If you have access to the MySQL database, go to the `wp_options` table and set the `siteurl` and `home` values to whatever they were before you edited them (when the site was still working).

Your site should hopefully be back after you make this change. If you edit the site address fields again, you must be very careful you have an understanding of what directory the WP core files are housed in before changing the URL.

### Fixing it in WP config

You could also manually override what's in the database by adding these lines to your `wp-config.php`. *(Change out example.com for your proper site address).*

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

But if you did it that way, you'd never be able to edit the Site URL in WP admin again. More info on this here:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

I'd always be careful when editing those URL fields in WP admin.

Hope that helps; perhaps I misunderstood the question.